# How to count specific array values and assign the values in a table data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here's my problem i have two arrays , one is multi dimensional array the second one is single array, these arrays is displayed in a two table. the multi-array is display in table 1 and single is in table 2. what i want to do is to count the number of employees for each position.

```
<?php include_once('fake_db.php'); ?>


<h3>Department List</h3>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Number of Employees</td><td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <?php foreach($positions as $key => $value){ ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?= $value; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?= $key; ?>">View Employee List</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

**fake_db.php**

```
$employees = array
             (
                 array("name" => 'Jason Alipala', "employee_id" => 'G1001-05', "position" => 1),
                 array("name" => 'Bryann Revina', "employee_id" => 'G1009-03', "position" => 2),
                 array("name" => 'Jeniel Mangahis', "employee_id" => 'G1009-04', "position" => 2),
                 array("name" => 'Arjay Bussala', "employee_id" => 'G1009-05', "position" => 3),
                 array("name" => 'Ronnel Ines', "employee_id" => 'G1002-06', "position" => 3)
             );

$positions = array(1 => 'TL', 2 => 'Programmer', 3 => 'Converter');
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean. Do you want to count the number of employees for each position?

Comment: Yes , i want to count the number of employees for each position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of employees for each position, you can use [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) on the `position` column of the the `employees` array. For example:

```
$emp_positions = array_count_values(array_column($employees, 'position'));
foreach ($positions as $key => $value) {
    echo $positions[$key] . ' : ' . $emp_positions[$key] . ' employees' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
TL : 1 employees 
Programmer : 2 employees 
Converter : 2 employees
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Aqp2J)

Comment: Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gleent\fake_db.php on line 27

Warning: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gleent\fake_db.php on line 27

Comment: How can i place the result also on my table data ?

Comment: @Diether I have used the data from your question (see the demo). I'm not sure why you're seeing that error?

Comment: @Diether where do you want to place the results?

Comment: I fix now, but how can i place the result in my table data ? not in echo
<?php foreach($positions as $key => $value){ ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?= $value; ?></td>
            <td><?= $emp_positions ?></td>
            <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?= $key; ?>">View Employee List</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: @Diether just use `$emp_positions[$key]` in that position. See my updated demo

Comment: How ? can you explain it in a code. I have a foreach loop already if i insert another foreach just to display the results it's not good

Comment: @Diether `<?php foreach($positions as $key => $value){ ?> <tr> <td><?= $value; ?></td> <td><?= $emp_positions[$key] ?></td> <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?= $key; ?>">View Employee List</a></td> </tr> <?php } ?>`